# (iOS/iPhone/XCode) textField and Buttons to submit data to Safari

Tags: xcode, ios, mapkit, mobile-safari

I'm trying to develop an application and am stuck at this specific part. I was previously taking a different approach through a web form displayed in UIWebView, but was having issues getting it to open how I wanted. I changed the UI and would now like to take this approach:

**Background**
User needs to be able to get directions to a specific shop location. The UI contains an instance of UIText Field and a round rect button. The User should be able to click the button and the default Maps application will pop up for the user.

*How I imagine this being coded:*

1) User enters address in `textField`
 - `textField` stores address as variable (`%var%`)
2) User presses `Go` button
 - Button adds variable (`%var%`) from `textField` to URL string (see below)
 - Button submits full URL to be opened in Safari
3) Safari opens request in Maps application


**Image Example** of UI: http://i55.tinypic.com/vnjc41.jpg

> http://maps.google.com/?saddr=**`%var%`**&daddr=123+Road+St%2C+Town%2C+CA+90210&hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way to do this using a button to open the maps application:

-(IBAction)hbgdirButton:(id)sender{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Harrisburg+PA&hl=en"]];
}